# Idles but no acceleration and battery signal is showing even when the alternator is charging on 2003 Murano

Tags: nissan, short, murano

on my 2003 Nissan Murano, a wire short occurred and melted many wires, I separated them and replaced the damaged wires. Now I have a code U1001, U1000, P1212 and so on, my car will start and only idle, no acceleration, indicates battery signal even when alternator is working.
I have removed my entire dashboard and diagnosed many components, cant find the issue. What can i do

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Seems like your CANBus isn't communicating correctly (U1000 & U1001). You still have an open circuit somewhere you haven't accounted for.

Comment: I suppose, Is it possible that it could be due to weak battery?

Comment: I'm doubting it, however, if you think it might be, charge it. If it's a bad battery, replace it.

Comment: Your battery has to be good and fully charged before any of these things can be properly diagnosed. But as mentioned above, I think there's more to it than just a weak battery.

Comment: I bought a new battery, checked and tightened all the ground terminals, grounded the ECU as it was not grounded while i was running the test. started it and its still the same thing.